# SwiftUI List listRowBackground opacity bug while dragging

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found a bug in `SwiftUI`'s `List` view where if the `listRowBackground` is set, the items will sometimes be opaque while dragging to reorder (instead of the default transparent views). Has anyone else encountered this or found any work-arounds for it?

[image: demonstration of bug]

I'm currently using Xcode 15 and iOS 17, and the issue *is* reproducible, as long as you are patient, since it is very sporadic.

Here is the code for the reproducible example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(editMode == .active ? "Done" : "Edit") {
                if editMode == .active {
                    editMode = .inactive
                } else {
                    editMode = .active
                }
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(1 ..< 11) { index in
                    Text("Item Number \(index)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: { _, _ in })
                .listRowBackground(Color.white)
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as I test my sample `List` app with iPhone 15 Sim, I don't see the said issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(editMode == .active ? "Done" : "Edit") {
                if editMode == .active {
                    editMode = .inactive
                } else {
                    editMode = .active
                }
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(1 ..< 11) { index in
                    Text("Item Number \(index)")
                        .background(Color.white) // Set background color directly
                }
                .onMove(perform: { _, _ in })
                .id(UUID()) // Force refresh
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately I have to use the `.listRowBackground` rather than setting the background on the item itself, because otherwise it won't color the background behind the entire cell (including the little drag icon that the `List` adds to the cell). Setting the id to force it to refresh was a good idea I hadn't thought of, but unfortunately it didn't fix the bug